# Query between two values in mongoose considering all posibilities

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So, I don't know how to describe the problem on a question, so here's the example:

Let's say I need to check out I need to make an appointment at this given time: startsAt: 8, endsAt: 11

But, these are the possibilities where the appointment cannot be done:

```
There's an appointment at 9 and it ends at 11; -- can't be done

There's an appointment at 8 and it ends at 10; -- can't be done

There's an appointment at 9 and it ends at 10; -- can't be done

There's an appointment at 7 and it ends at 12. -- can't be done
```

For the three first possibilities, I do have an idea on how to do the query; however, for the last possibility, I do not. I am a newbie in using mongoose, so I truly don't know how to accomplish it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({
  "$and": [
    {
      "start": {
        "$lte": 11
      }
    },
    {
      "end": {
        "$gte": 8
      }
    }
  ]
})/**8,11*/
```

[Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SYYGeFv20x7)

I just added logic based on

```
t1 = [8,10]

t2 = [8,11]

 isBefore = !t1.end.isBefore(t2.begin) 
                     && !t1.begin.isAfter(t2.end);
```

Comment: Wow, it really was that easy; I was complicating myself. Thank you very much for the help and that tool, it'll help me out.